# jQuery + AJAX append with Fade

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, fadein

I have followed the tutorials based at:
http://technotip.com/2208/insert-data-into-mysql-jquery-ajax-php/
and
http://technotip.com/2298/fetchextract-data-from-database-without-refreshing-webpage-jquery/

And these are working great.

My question is, how do I go about creating the following process:

When the page loads, all existing records appear in the **ul** tag normally. But once the page has loaded, any new appended **li** items fade in.

```
function updates() {
 $.getJSON("pullsql.php", function(data) {
   $("ul").empty();
   $.each(data.result, function(){
    //$("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><br />");
    $('<div></div>').appendTo("ul").hide().append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><br />").fadeIn('slow');
   });
  });
 }
```

So far I've tried changing the updates() function to the above (original line commented out, changed line below it).

This is causing the entire **ul** list to fade in every 200ms (the update timer) but I need each **li** to only fadeIn one time only.

Thanks in advance for any help and happy to be redirected to an appropriate tutorial to help me learn rather than just being fed code.

****EDIT**********

I think the following functions are causing issues with the answers so far:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Could this be done using a counter and giving the li's an ID? So 4 li's are loaded initially and the count = 4. A new LI is then appended with ID = count + 1 and because ID > Count it is faded In and after the fade the count is increased by one so all LIs with an ID equal to or less than the count no longer fade?

I imagine this might work but wouldn't know how to implement the javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work using the following - thanks to the guy who provided the .new class idea but has since removed his answer. This works by using the auto-increment id in MySQL. For records that UPDATE rather than just INSERT then I guess I could add a timestamp on update and have var ulid = to the previous records timestamp

```
var ulid = 0;
function updates() {
  $.getJSON("pullsql.php", function(data) {
     $("ul").empty();
     $.each(data.result, function(){

     if (ulid >= this['id']){
        $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><br />");
     } else {
        $("ul li").removeClass("new"); 
        $("ul").append('<li class="new">Name: '+this['name']+'</li><li class="new">Age: '+this['age']+'</li><br />');
        $("ul li.new").fadeIn('slow');
        ulid = this['id'];
    }
       });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have `<div>` inside `<ul>`

try this

```
function updates() {
  $.getJSON("pullsql.php", function(data) {
     $("ul").empty();
     $.each(data.result, function(){
          var newli=  "<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><br />"; 
          $(newli).appendTo("ul").hide().fadeIn('slow');

   });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this:

```
var newLi = $("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li>
               <li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li><br />");

newLi.css('display','none').appendTo('ul');
$('ul li:last-child').fadeIn('slow');
```